# Continuity and topology

Tags: real-analysis

Let a set X  and two topologies on X,$\tau_1,\tau_2$ with $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 $.I want prove :

1) $id_X : (X,\tau_2) \rightarrow (X,\tau_1)$ is continuous (identity map)

2) given a topological space Y if $g:(X,\tau_1) \rightarrow Y$ is continuous then $g:(X,\tau_2) \rightarrow Y$ is continuous

My attemp:

1) if $A \in \tau_1$ is an open set, $(id_X(A))^{-1}=A \in \tau_2$ so $id_X$ is continuous

but for the second point?

Comment: Shouln't the second point be : "given a topological space $Y$ if $g\colon(X,\tau_1) \to Y$ is continous, then $g\colon (X,\tau_2) \to Y$ is continous" ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subseteq Y$ be an open set. Then by continuity $g^{-1}(U)\in\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subset Y$ be an open set. Then $g^{-1}(A)\in \tau_1\subset \tau_2$ so $g^{-1}(A)\in \tau_2$. Hence $g:(X,\tau_2)\to Y$ is continous